# Is it possible to have a "safe_eval" for primitive math expressions in Python?

Tags: security, python-3.x, cpython

While there are many questions on SE regarding sand-boxing CPython, most focus on providing a more or less complete Python environment.

In this case, I'm interested in using Python for basic math expressions, something of this complexity, eg:

`(sin(a) * cos(b) / tan(c) ** sqrt(d)) -  e`

Now I could create my own expression evaluator *in* Python, however I don't want to sacrifice performance *(or have to maintain it and have good Python compatibility for all the corner cases)*.

I looked into [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) and [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr), both very interesting projects, but neither have security/sand-boxing as a goal.

I considered writing a minimal version of `ceval.c` which runs a restricted set of CPython's bytecodes, but this is still quite some effort.

Instead I did a [quick test](https://github.com/ideasman42/py_safe_math_eval) that restricts name-space and checks the compiled expressions opcodes before executing, from my initial tests this works well, though I'm not totally confident its *secure* either.

While this isn't clear-cut, using simple expressions means I don't necessarily need:

- multiple lines of code.
- import statements.
- defining functions & classes.
- getattr or getitem access.
- for & while loops.

---

So my question is:

Is there a reliably *secure* way to execute math expressions in CPython that can co-exist in the same process as complete CPython scripts?

---

Note, since *security* may be too vague a term, for the purpose of discussion.
Reading or removing files on the users system.
Running `open` or any functions in `os` or `shutil`.

Comment: Question is too vague.  Security is in relation to a threat.  This might be better discussed on python-list, accessible at news.gmane.org as gmane.comp.python.general.

Comment: Attempted to clarify *security* (see footnote).

Comment: With the 'in the same process' condition, I am sure that the answer to the clarified question is 'no'.  Even in a separate process, it is difficult to absolutely prevent access, from within Python, to the open function.  Caging the process from the OS (by the OS ignoring calls to the system open function) seems to be more reliable.  I believe that this is the approach of web sites that execute submitted code.